# Replace for-loop in SQL

Tags: sql, for-loop

I have a table in a database. For example table of user IDs and right IDs:

```
UserId  RightId
---------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       2
3       3
4       1
4       2
5       1
6       1
6       2
```

What is the best way to insert for each userId new rightId 4?

I heard that using while or for loops is not the best way to do such thing.
Can you please show me an example how to solve such problem with JOINs and SETs for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (UserID, RightID)
SELECT  DISTINCT
        UserID,
        4
FROM    MyTable
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f51ba/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to change every entry in the RightId column you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET RightId=4;
```

Comment: taht is not what I want ot do, I want to add to each userId another new rightID